# boost::filesystem::path::lexically_normal: is this incorrect behavior?

Tags: c++, boost

The documentation of `boost::filesystem::path::lexically_normal()` states:

> Returns `*this` with redundant current directory (dot), parent directory (dot-dot), and directory-separator elements removed.

See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html.

The following prints `./test` (using Boost 1.63.0) where I would expect `test`:

```
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
   std::cout << boost::filesystem::path{"./test"}.lexically_normal().string() << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

So the first dot element is not considered redundant. However, both `test` and `./test` obviously resolve to the same file when using boost filesystem, so this seems inconsistent to me. Is this expected behavior?

*Update*: the C++17 filesystem library returns `"test"` as expected (GCC 8.2.0, Linux).

Comment: You're implicitly assuming here that `test` is a relative path. That's a dangerous assumption in portable code. `./test` is unambiguously relative.

Comment: It is a Unix sensibility.  Hardly where it ends, the 0777 that roots `perms` will never port well to a non-Unix OS.

Answer (score 2):

It is reasonable behaviour, because although you are right that `test` and `./test` usually refer to the same thing, this is not the case everywhere.

For example, if you run `./test` as a command in a shell, it will always look for that program in the current directory and nowhere else.   But if you run `test` it will look in the runtime path (e.g. `$PATH`) instead.

So whether `test` and `./test` refer to the same file is actually context dependent--therefore the `./` is not redundant.

Comment: I tought about this, and I am not convinced. The usage of paths in the context of `boost::filesystem` should not be context-dependent. We are dealing with filesystem paths, not terminal commands.

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel: Who are we to say what sort of paths are used in Boost Filesystem?  I am pretty sure some people would in fact use this library to manipulate paths which are later used in shell commands.  Of course you can always look at the unit tests provided in Boost Filesystem to see if they explicitly note this outcome.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had a look at the test cases, a dot prefix is not covered.

Comment: FYI, the C++17 filesystem library does return `"test"` in this case (GCC 8.2.0/Linux).